# Rails does not consider `DATABASE_URL` in the `test` environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I'm using `docker-compose` to create two services for my Rails application:

- `web` - the actual Rails/web app
- `db` - A postgres container running postgres 11.5

I'm running both services locally with `RAILS_ENV=development`.

As a one-time manual step I want to The very first time I try to run `rake db:create` to create the database. However, I get a postgres connection error:

```
docker-compose up --build --no-start
docker-compose run --rm web bundle exec rake db:create

RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:create
Created database 'feeder_development'
could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
  Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Couldn't create 'feeder_test' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
  Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb:45:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb:45:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb:45:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:692:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:223:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:48:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:48:in `postgresql_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:811:in `new_connection'
```

As you can see, it **successfully** created the `development` database, but **failed** on creating the `test` database

(The `db:create` tasks automatically creates `test` and `development` databases together even when the environment is `development`)

Here is my `database.yml`.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  min_messages: warning
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  <<: *default
  database: feeder_test

development:
  <<: *default
  database: feeder_development
```

According to the [Rails guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database), you can override the above config by specifying a `DATABASE_URL`, which I set as:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://feeder:password123@db/
```

So from what I can tell -

1. Rails merges the `DATABASE_URL` info with the `database.yml` info when trying to create the `development` database. All is good.
2. Rails does NOT consider the `DATABASE_URL` at all when creating the `test` database. It uses ONLY the `database.yml` info, which is why it's looking for a psql connection on `localhost`.

So - is there a way to get Rails to respect my `DATABASE_URL` ENV on the `test` environment?

Answer (score 3):

in your `database.yml` set `url` to `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` and leave other keys as defaults:

```
test:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  database: app_test
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

```
DATABASE_URL='postgresql://192.168.0.2/' rails runner 'puts ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.to_json' | jq '.test'
{
  "database": "app_test",
  "host": "192.168.0.2",
  "adapter": "postgresql"
}
```

Notice that database name left unchanged but host has been overwritten.

Comment: Wow what a simple solution - thanks! Doesn't it seem odd that `test` would not respect `DATABASE_URL` by default? It feels counter-intuitive to have to specify that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can put ERB into the database.yml file, so I'd suggest changing `test` to

```
test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'feeder_test' %>
```